# Single Linebreak in Jade HTML Output

Tags: pug

I am trying to get a single linebreak inside of Jade HTML output for a child tag. I'm already using the `--pretty` option for compiling.

If I use:

```
h1.neighborhood
    |<%= neighborhood %>
```

I get:

```
<h1 class="neighborhood"><%= neighborhood %></h1>
```

On the other hand, if I use (space after top line)

```
h1.neighborhood 
    <%= neighborhood %>
```

I get:

```
<h1 class="neighborhood">

  <%= neighborhood %>
</h1>
```

Absurdity. How do I get this?

```
<h1 class="neighborhood">       
  <%= neighborhood %>
</h1>
```

Comment: Why does this matter to you? It shouldn't affect the browser's rendering.

Comment: I have colleagues who don't use Jade and will sometimes need to read the HTML output.